# Active Directory | Attribute Editor - get user attribute with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My client create few attributes fields in his AD.

I am trying to get those files by Microsoft graph API.
is it possible?

those files do not return when I select them

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=XXX

if it is not possible, what is the alternative?

thanks

Comment: How did you client create attributes fields? Using this `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions`?

Comment: no, he didnt use microsoft graph. and I think the attributes are in his local AD.

Comment: Please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions). You need to added a custom attribute on the users schema on the local AD, and then configured it to sync as an extension property to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

@Shiva is right.

You can [customize which attributes to synchronize with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions#customize-which-attributes-to-synchronize-with-azure-ad).

> During installation of Azure AD Connect, an application is registered
> where these attributes are available. You can see this application in
> the Azure portal. Its name is always **Tenant Schema Extension App**.
>
> The attributes are prefixed with **extension_{ApplicationId}_**.

Then you could select the attributes through Microsoft Graph like this: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{object id}?$select=extension_{ApplicationId}_employeeID`.